# How to access to columns in data frame uploaded in shiny app?

Tags: file-io, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app. This app uses a .csv file uploaded by the user. I do not really understand how fileInput() works in the sense of storing the data frame.

I am using this code to upload the file:

> ```
>   data_OBS = reactive({
>     inFile <- input$file1
>     if (is.null(inFile))
>       return(NULL)
>     read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T, sep=",")
>   })
> ```

If I understood well, the data frame should be accesible in data_OBS(). If the .csv file I want to upload has a column named for example "CL" in normal R enviorement I should be able to access using data_OBS$CL. However, in shiny data_OBS() is a function. I have tried data_OBS$CL, data_OBS()$CL, data_OBS(CL) but none of them worked. How can access to the data just uploaded?

Thanks in advance,

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `data_OBS()$CL`, but only inside reactive context such as `observe`, `observeEvent`, `eventReactive`.

Here is a minimal example using `observeEvent`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File"),
  textOutput("text"),
  actionButton("print", "Print to text output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  data_OBS = reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T, sep=",")
  })

  observeEvent(input$print, {
    req(input$file1) # Doesn't do anything until a file is uploaded
    output$text <- renderText(data_OBS()$CL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -1):

First to check it did not return null. Also, you may force return(read.csv(...))
data_OBS()$CL should work.